# Parameter values for parameter (n_estimators) need to be a sequence

Tags: python

I am getting the error, not sure how to fix it. Can you please help. The entire code can be found at https://github.com/kthouz/NYC_Green_Taxi/blob/master/NYC%20Green%20Taxi.ipynb

## optimize n_estimator through grid search

```
def optimize_num_trees(alg,param_test,scoring_method,train,predictors,target):
    """
    This functions is used to tune paremeters of a predictive algorithm
    alg: sklearn model,
    param_test: dict, parameters to be tuned
    scoring_method: str, method to be used by the cross-validation to valuate the model
    train: pandas.DataFrame, training data
    predictors: list, labels to be used in the model training process. They should be in the column names of dtrain
    target: str, target variable
    """
    gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=alg, param_grid = param_test, scoring=scoring_method,n_jobs=2,iid=False,cv=5)
    gsearch.fit(train[predictors],train[target])
    return gsearch

# get results of the search grid
gs_cls = optimize_num_trees(model_cls,param_test,'roc_auc',train,predictors,target)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-c7419a90cdb1> in <module>()
      1 
      2 # get results of the search grid
----> 3 gs_cls = optimize_num_trees(model_cls,param_test,'roc_auc',train,predictors,target)
      4 

<ipython-input-40-2b76f2ffb87f> in optimize_num_trees(alg, param_test, scoring_method, train, predictors, target)
     57     target: str, target variable
     58     """
---> 59     gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=alg, param_grid = param_test, scoring=scoring_method,n_jobs=2,iid=False,cv=5)
     60     gsearch.fit(train[predictors],train[target])
     61     return gsearch

/Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py in __init__(self, estimator, param_grid, scoring, fit_params, n_jobs, iid, refit, cv, verbose, pre_dispatch, error_score)
    810             refit, cv, verbose, pre_dispatch, error_score)
    811         self.param_grid = param_grid
--> 812         _check_param_grid(param_grid)
    813 
    814     def fit(self, X, y=None):

/Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py in _check_param_grid(param_grid)
    346             if True not in check:
    347                 raise ValueError("Parameter values for parameter ({0}) need "
--> 348                                  "to be a sequence.".format(name))
    349 
    350             if len(v) == 0:

ValueError: Parameter values for parameter (n_estimators) need to be a sequence.
```

Comment: Check the `param_test` variable. See if you have initialized it correctly. It should be dictionary or a list of dictionaries. The link you added declares `param_test` as a dictionary. `param_test = {'n_estimators':range(50,200,25)}`. You can also try using `param_test = {'n_estimators':list(range(50,200,25))}` if it needs a list and not a generator.

Comment: Can you read that? I can't...

Comment: Edit your question and use the `{}` button above the edit box to format your code as code so it doesn't reflow.

Comment: {'n_estimators':list(range(50,200,25))} Adding this fixed it. Thank you!!!

Comment: @ClockSlave    found same issue and ` params = {'max_depth': list(range(1,11))}` helped me out too, can anyone please help me why was this issue coming? what I was missing in writing like `params = {'max_depth': range(1,11)}`?

Comment: I think that’s because range() returns a generator instead of a list which is what is required. If you don’t know the difference I’d suggest you look them up.

Comment: @Victor were you able to get this entire code (the code which build the regression random forest) going ? Please reply here and let me know

Answer (score 12):

I got a similar error as you:

> ValueError: Parameter values for parameter (warm_start) need to be a
>   sequence(but not a string) or np.ndarray. site:stackoverflow.com

The Value for each Key apparently needs to be in array brackets [ ]

My erroneous code:

```
params = {
    'max_depth': [11],
    'warm_start': True
}
```

My correct code:

```
params = {
    'max_depth': [11],
    'warm_start': [True]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I met a similar error like you,  in the following code:

```
# optimize n_estimator through grid search
# define range over which number of trees is to be optimized
param_test = {'n_estimators':range(30,151,20)}
```

you can change

`range(30,151,20)` to `np.arange(30,151,20)`

Answer (score 2):

GridSearchCV expects the parameter values in a sequence format, so always you should give the parameter values in the form of a list or numpy array even if the parameter value is a single value.

For example:
if you give the below dictionary for GridSearchCV it raises an error, since the value of n_jobs -1 is a single integer and not sequence(list or array).

parameters={'alpha':[0.01, 0.1, 1, 10], 'n_jobs':-1}

but if you wrap the -1 in a list and give to GridSearchCV it wont raise any errors.
parameters={'alpha':[0.01,0.1,1,10], 'n_jobs': [-1]}

Hope it helps.